# Problemas com a fórmula de uma condição "Else", "IF", "ElseIf"?

Tags: if, script, condição, else

Ao realizarmos o cálculo de um indicador, quando os dois valores calculados são negativos, a fórmula atual acaba por somar o valor, por exemplo **(-+-=+)**. Segue a mesma:

```
IF(@ISMBR(@ILSIBLINGS("FY22")))

    "Lucro / Prejuízo Antes I.R." + "Impostos sobre o Lucro";

ELSE

    IF("Impostos sobre o Lucro" > 0)

        "Lucro / Prejuízo Antes I.R." - "Impostos sobre o Lucro";

    ELSE

        "Lucro / Prejuízo Antes I.R." + "Impostos sobre o Lucro";

    ENDIF
ENDIF
```

Desta forma, gostaria de entender como posso aplicar alguma condição que quando estes dois indicadores "lucro\prejuízo e Impostos sobre o lucro" forem negativos, não realize a soma e sim a subtração.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar uma condição `IF` para verificar se cada um dos valores é menor que zero. Se ambos forem menores que zero, então você pode subtrair o valor do imposto sobre o lucro do lucro/prejuízo antes do imposto de renda.

```
IF(@ISMBR(@ILSIBLINGS("FY22")))
"Lucro / Prejuízo Antes I.R." + "Impostos sobre o Lucro";

ELSEIF("Lucro / Prejuízo Antes I.R." < 0 AND "Impostos sobre o Lucro" < 0)

"Lucro / Prejuízo Antes I.R." - "Impostos sobre o Lucro";

ELSEIF("Impostos sobre o Lucro" > 0)

"Lucro / Prejuízo Antes I.R." - "Impostos sobre o Lucro";

ELSE

"Lucro / Prejuízo Antes I.R." + "Impostos sobre o Lucro";

ENDIF
```

A condição `IF` foi substituída por uma condição `ELSEIF` para permitir a verificação adicional dos valores negativos. A nova condição `ELSEIF` verifica se ambos os valores são negativos e, se for o caso, realiza a subtração ao invés da soma.

Comment: Pedro e Marcos, muito obrigado pela ajuda! Deu certo aqui. Sucesso para vocês!!